# wordpress на главной странице не работает плеер с playlist'ом

Tags: wordpress, плагин, аудио

На главной странице, работает через home.php, не работают плееры. 
 Ставил плагины MP3-jPlayer, PB oEmbed HTML5 Audio, HTML5 jQuery Audio Player. Даже встроенный через шорткод `[playlist]` пробовал. На всех страницах кроме главной они работают.
Дальше магия: удаляю всё содержимое, кроме `get_header()` и самого шорт кода - не работает(одни не отображаются, например стандартный, другие просто не активны). Делаю вывод, что содержимое ни при чём. На других страницах плееры работают, значит конфликт подключенных библиотек или ещё чего-то в header.php тоже отпадает.
Остаётся только механика отображения главной страницы (возможно что-то с редиректом), но плееры работают на локалхосте на чистом wordpress. Создавал главную страницу не страницей новостей, а менял на статичную, в настройках, результат тот же. На этом мои варианты практически исчерпаны.

Пожалуйста, подскажите где я ошибаюсь в рассуждениях или чего не учитываю? Хоть какие-то варианты, буду очень признателен.

Comment: кстати, некоторые плееры без playlist работают, а с ним нет.

Answer (score 1):

Локализовал проблему. На версии 4.4.2 действительно не работают. Обновление решило проблему с плеером, но заруинило часть функционала самописной темы. Пришлось делать откат. 
В конечном итоге решил проблему через велосипед: тег `<audio>` и самописный playlist на  jquery. Вероятнее всего проблема именно в конфликте версий библиотек.
Таким образом, прямого решения не нашёл, как и не нащупал основную причину.
Надеюсь, что никому не пригодится.